# Regular expression for separating optional trailing number from a string

Tags: regex

I need to separate a name from a numeric ID in a string like

> Mr. John Smith 1111

where the ID in the end is optional.

So it should be 2 capturing groups - one for the name and the optional other for the numeric ID.

I've come up with the following [regular expression:](https://regex101.com/r/Ro5keG/1)

```
/^(?P<name>[^\d]+)(?P<id>(?<= )\d+)?$/
```

The questions are:

1. How to trim the the `name` group? Currently I'm getting spaces in the end of it.
2. How to allow the name to contain numbers? If I replace `[^\d]` to `.*` in the `name` group, it captures the whole string.
3. Can you think of any better version of a regex for this string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?P<name>.+?)(?:\s+(?P<id>\d+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dQFSRv/2).

**Details**

- `^` - [start of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758874/when-to-use-this-symbol-in-regex/22759143#22759143)
- `(?P<name>.+?)` - Group "name" that captures 1 or more chars other than line break chars *as few as possible* as `*?` is a [lazy quantifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) (i.e. this pattern matches the first char first, and then is skipped, the subsequent subpatterns are tried, and only when they fail, this one is "expanded")
- `(?:\s+(?P<id>\d+))?` - an optional [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471) that matches

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars
  - `(?P<id>\d+)` - Group "id": 1+ digits
- `$` - [end of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758874/when-to-use-this-symbol-in-regex/22759143#22759143).